# Problem with solr search

Tags: solr, solrnet

My solr xml file is like

```
<doc><UserId>12</UserId><UserIdInCommunity>1</UserIdInCommunity><CommunityId>1</CommunityId><UserEmail>gaurav@somemail.com</UserEmail></doc><doc><UserId>12</UserId><UserIdInCommunity>2</UserIdInCommunity><CommunityId>3</CommunityId><UserEmail>gaurav@somemail.com</UserEmail></doc>
```

It is clear from here that the user with id 12 exists in two communities but when I search it in solr with a query "UserEmail:gaurav@somemail.com", it returns only one record, while if I search it with free text, I mean "gaurav@somemail.com", it returns proper records.

Please help.
Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: is that XML snippet a field value? if so, what's the corresponding field type? if not, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Is UserEmail a string field? If so you have an extra ">" in your document after the email address: "gaurav@somemail.com>". String fields require an exact match unless you use a *, so you might want to check your XML. You also might want to try a wildcard search like:

```
 UserEmail:gaurav@somemail.com*
```

Finally, I would search for the specific userID that doesn't show up in your query, like:

```
 UserId:12
```

This will tell you what their email is set to after it is indexed.

One more question I have is what are you using for your ID field in your index? If you have multiple records with the same user ID or email and that is your ID, then you will only get one record (Solr will update the record instead of add a new one).

Comment: Sorry for I made a typo with email. As I had typed it manually, a ">" had been added there. As far as my problem is concerned, I had updated the schema file for some reason and didn't re-post the xml. That is why solr's behavior was weird. After reindexing, the problem disappeared. Thanks.